# webpack-dev-server historyApiFallback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webpack, router, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to implement my version of client side rendering. Thus, I want to handle routing from my `router.js` that gets imported from `index.html`.

So I added a `historyAPIFallback` but it doesnt seem to work.

I tried 2 methods both directing to `localhost/post/1/test`,

1. from [official guide](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback)

```js
// webpack.config.js
devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{ from: /.*/, to: './src/index.html' }],
    },
  },
```

this outputs:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

pointing at the first `<html>` tag.

2. from stackoverflow (which seems like an old solution)

```js
// webpack.config.js
devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: './src/index.html',
    },
  },
```

this outputs:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/post/1/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea to fix what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

solution that worked for me was adding `/` in `index.html` where i imported `index.js`

before:

```html
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

after:

```html
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```